# unable to install pyqt4 with multiple methods

Tags: python, windows, powershell, makefile, pyqt4

I've been having a ton of issues in general trying to install packages on python 3 on windows. I don't know if any issues are related or not, I'm just going to try to provide as much detail to these issues as I can.

It's not just PYQT, but a couple packages are giving me issues with installing. I have a python 3.5.1 virtual environment, and when I try to install PYQT4 it gives me the error (using pip, pip3, with and without --pre):

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt4
```

This isn't the only package that has given me this exact same error, but I can't recall atm what other packages gave me issues. (Another issue I often get with other packages is error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat. I've been through all the questions regarding that error, installing visual c fails for me).

So I decided to try to download the zip and follow this guide: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html , which has me following this guide to install SIP as a requirement: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html#downloading .

So now I'm having more problems. Part of the installation process for SIP requires using a makefile. So I downloaded make from cygwin. I run python configure.py to generate the makefile (in the proper virtualenv), and I run make, but make never ends. It keeps reading this over and over again until I kill powershell or cmd:

```
cd sipgen
/usr/bin/make
make[453]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/<username>/.virtualenvs/<envname>/sip-4.17'
```

That directory is the location of the makefile. I'm completely inexperienced with make, so any help would be appreciated. All of these problems are while using Python 3. My python 2 virtual environments are able to install most packages fine.

Edit: My mistake, in this case it's giving the same pip error with python 2 and 3.

Comment: Why aren't you using the [binary packages](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download)?

Comment: It just installs the directory in the site-packages, but it's not showing up on freeze.

Comment: The package doesn't show up on pip freeze, nor in pycharm ide package list

Comment: I think you should clarify what question you want answering. Are you asking "how to compile PyQt in a virtual env on windows?" or would you prefer an answer to "How to make PyQt, installed via binary, show up in pip freeze and pycharm?". Your question currently has a lot of statements that cover problems, but no clear explanation of what you are actually aiming for.

Comment: Try to install the package from the Windows pre-compiled binaries: [~gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4)